# iPod touch (iOS4) doesn't sync AddressBook after moving to iCloud

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, mobileme, contacts

I moved from MobileMe to iCloud. So my iPod2gn blocked in iOS4 is not part of the sync anymore. Well, it's a technical and commercial shame, but well, ok, enough said.

I wanted to be able to have my Calendar and Address book sync by iTunes when I plug my iPod to my iMac.

It works for emails, photos, calendars BUT not the AddressBook.

Is this a known issue or am I missing some basic stuff here?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, after moving to iCloud, iTunes won't sync Address Book with an iOS4 device, as there is some sort of *issue* with folder paths.

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16860623#16860623) is the only thing I could find addressing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly what you asked for, but it might help:

You can sync your Address Book and Calendar to a GMail account. [Google's instructions](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) for this are fine, so I won't repeat them here. If you sync your Mac/PC to the GMail contacts as well, this will give you similar functionality to iCloud, even on iOS4.